# jQuery: add a specific class to the last row of a grid of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a small, responsive, blogging application. The posts are displayed as boxes.

I would like to add, to all the posts on the last row, a `last-row` class. I am using `.position().top` to find the items located the farthest from the top of their parent element:

```js
$('.posts-grid>[class*="col-"]').each(function() {
  var $item = $(this),
    posTop = $item.position().top;
  console.log(posTop);
});
```

```css
.posts-grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.posts-grid .text {
  padding: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .card-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}

.posts-grid .text-muted {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.posts-grid p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  margin-top: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="posts-grid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
          <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
        </div>
        <div class="read-more">
          <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I "catch" all those items "located the farthest" and add each of them a class name?

Of course, I want this collection of items to be updated at `$(window).resize()`.

Comment: Its responsive, so you want only those cells (`div`s) on the final row to get the class? Did I understand that right?

Comment: Use the [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, `$(window).resize()` caoud be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as 2 steps

1. Find the maximum top position
2. filter the cells to find the ones with that maximum top position and apply whatever transformation you like (in my example just applies class `last-row`)

As an extra complexity of this method, you need to recalculate on resize.

```js
function setup() {

  var maxTop = $('.posts-grid>[class*="col-"]').removeClass("last-row").map(function() {
    var $item = $(this)
    return $item.position().top;    
  }).get().reduce( (acc,curr) => (curr>acc)? curr : acc)

  $('.posts-grid>[class*="col-"]').filter( function(){
     var $item = $(this)
    return $item.position().top == maxTop;    
  }).addClass("last-row");

}

setup();
$(window).resize(setup);
```

```css
.posts-grid {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
}

.posts-grid .text {
  padding: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .card-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}

.posts-grid .text-muted {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.posts-grid .thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.posts-grid p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.posts-grid .post {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.posts-grid .last-row .post {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.posts-grid .read-more {
  margin-top: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .posts-grid>[class*='col-'] {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="posts-grid">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
    <div class="post">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeOrf.jpg"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3 class="card-title">Sunt aut facere repellat provident</h3>
        <p class="text-muted ng-binding">Quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum reprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam nostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto</p>
      </div>
      <div class="read-more">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-primary" href="#">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The script works, but only if I use it for *one* grid. I wish to use it for multiple `<div class="grid">Items here</div>` on one page. How can I do that?

Comment: The script works on some *grids* I have on the page, but not on *all* of them. On those it does not work on there is this error: `Reduce of empty array with no initial value`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your container's last elements' count will vary according to the window size (breakpoint), you should consider using a CSS approach.

```css
.col-xs-12 {
   border: solid 1px blue;
}

.posts-grid > div:nth-last-child(-n+1){
  border: dashed 1px red;
}

/* use your prefered breakpoints */
/* SM */
@media screen and (min-width: 575px){
   .posts-grid > div:nth-last-child(-n+2){
      border: dashed 1px red;
   }
}
/* LG */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
   .posts-grid > div:nth-last-child(-n+3){
      border: dashed 1px red;
   }
}
/* XL */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
   .posts-grid > div:nth-last-child(-n+4){
      border: dashed 1px red;
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row posts-grid">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        POST1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        POST2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        POST3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        POST4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        POST5
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
      <div class="post">
        POST6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**IMPORTANT**: This will only work as long as you have a full last row.

Comment: css is a better solution to this IMO than my programmatic one.